# Self-signed (jdk 7u45) Applet got NullPointerException when runs on SSL in firefox and chrome

Tags: java, applet, nullpointerexception, java-7

I am using an applet in my web application.
I create self-signed applet jar file and compile classes using Oracle **JDK 1.7.45**.
In client side, I use **JRE 1.7.51** and import the certificate.
The applet works fine in three browsers (IE, Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome) when I use the application on SSL protocol. The problem is that I got the following NullPointerException when I try to run applet in the chrome and Firefox browser while using the application in http without SSL mode, but it still works in IE.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.getTrustedCodeSources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.strategy(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.openClassPathElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u45-relnotes-2016950.html , I see these 2 related 7u45 known issues:

> **Area**: Deployment/Plugin
>
> **Synopsis**: Applet could fail to load by throwing NPE if pack compression is used with deployment caching disabled.
>
> If a JAR file is using pack compression with manifest entries
>   Permissions and Caller-Allowable-Codebase while deployment caching is
>   disabled, then:
>
> •    The Permissions manifest entry will be ignored. (This can be seen
>   from the fact that yellow warning is there on security dialog even
>   though the Permissions attribute is there.) This only happens if
>   Caller-Allowable-Codebase attribute is present along with the
>   Permissions attribute.
>
> •    The Caller-Allowable-Codebase attribute will cause the applet to
>   fail to load by throwing a java.lang.NullPointerException.
>
> If you want to use pack compression with the
>   Caller-Allowable-Codebase attribute, there are two possible
>   workarounds:
>
> • Enable caching and all issues listed will disappear.
>
> •    Do not use the pack property jnlp.packEnabled=true while deploying
>   the applets using Caller-Allowable-Codebase andpremissions property.
>   Instead use the ContentType servlet for serving the pack files.
>
> **Area:** Deployment/Plugin
>
> **Synopsis**: Non-JNLP trusted applet fails to load using the file:\ URL. Local trusted applets that do not deploy using a JNLP file will
>   fail to load by throwing a java.lang.NullPointerException. You can
>   work around this issue by using one of the following methods:
>
> • Use a JNLP file to launch the applet.
>
> • Try loading the applet over HTTP or HTTPS.

But I don’t use pack compression, also I use a JNLP file to launch the applet and the problem continues to appear.

Comment: Try raising a new bug report..

Answer (score 2):

If your web application is accessed via an authentication step, it is possible that the Java plugins for Chrome and Firefox are unable to download the jar files - when they try to access the URL for the applet, they most probably are greeted by your login page. You could confirm this with Fiddler.

This problem does not appear in IE, because the Java plugin is able to use the session held by the browser itself, so the applet loader is able to immediately download the jar file.

If this is the case for you, the obvious solution is to allow unauthenticated access to the jar file. If you are using IIS, this is done by adding exceptions in web.config.

Comment: Exactly what I need. U made my day!